# Failing to create a virtualenv using python3.7 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, python3, pip, virtualenv

I have a system running `Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS` which comes with `python3.8` by default. For some work purposes, I need to use a virtual environment in `python 3.7`. So, I installed `python3.7` which has been successfully installed.

The output for `$ python3.7 --version` results in `Python 3.7.15` as output and `$ python3.7` results in python3.7 shell.

So, now I installed `pip` using, (as per documentations)

`$ sudo apt install python3-venv python3-pip`

`$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

For installing `virtualenv` I went via,

`$ python3.7 -m pip install virtualenv`

which went without a hitch.

Now to create my virtual environment, I went through,
`$ python3.7 -m virtualenv /path/to/venv/`

which fails by giving me a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'` error,

The entire output being,

```py
$ python3.7 -m virtualenv /path/to/venv/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "_main_", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_main_.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 19, in <module>
    from distutils.util import strtobool
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'
```

How do I go forth resolving this? all I want is a `python3.7` virtual environment in a `Ubuntu 20.04` system.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by installing `distutils` for `python3.7` by `$ sudo apt install python3.7-distutils`

This fixed the issue and i was able to create the virtualenv successfully.

Only thing i had to keep in mind was to use `pip3.7` in the virtual environment since the `pip` installed initially was based on `python 3.8.10`